# Twinfield every SOAP request failed

Tags: soap, twinfield

Before this project I never worked with SOAP. So I followed all of the instructions from: https://wktaaeu.force.com/nlcommunity/s/article/Setting-up-OAuth-2-0-Introduction?language=en_US and used the Postman templates on that page to make SOAP requests.

After a while I got the Access Token and company code, but I can't find out how to make other requests. With every request that I try to make from different sources on the internet I get the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</faultstring>
            <detail />
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Im making a mistake why every request fails but I can't figure it out.

### Examples of different requests I tried

This one I took from: [Postman Twinfield API request deleted transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72213409/postman-twinfield-api-request-deleted-transactions)

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <h:Authentication xmlns:h="http://www.twinfield.com/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AccessToken xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Twinfield.WebServices.Shared">ACCESS_TOKEN</AccessToken>
            <CompanyCode xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Twinfield.WebServices.Shared">35f3248f-46cc-4a8e-b16c-69ac65118771</CompanyCode>
        </h:Authentication>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <Query i:type="b:GetDeletedTransactions" xmlns="http://www.twinfield.com/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Twinfield.WebServices" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Twinfield.WebServices.DeletedTransactionsService">
            <b:CompanyCode>COMPANY_CODE</b:CompanyCode>
            <b:DateFrom>2022-01-01T00:00:00</b:DateFrom>
            <b:DateTo>2022-12-31T23:59:00</b:DateTo>
            <b:Daybook></b:Daybook>
        </Query>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Second try was by myself from the docs:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:twin="http://www.twinfield.com/">
<soapenv:Header>
    <twin:Header>
         <twin:AccessToken>ACCESS_TOKEN</twin:AccessToken>
      </twin:Header>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <twin:ProcessXmlString>
         <twin:xmlRequest><![CDATA[<list><type>offices</type></list>]]></twin:xmlRequest>
      </twin:ProcessXmlString>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Last one also made by my reading the docs:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:twinfield="http://www.twinfield.com/">
    <soap:Header>
        <twinfield:Header>
            <twinfield:AccessToken>ACCESS_TOKEN</twinfield:AccessToken>
            <twinfield:CompanyCode>COMPANY_CODE</twinfield:CompanyCode>
        </twinfield:Header>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <twinfield:ProcessXmlDocument>
            <twinfield:xmlRequest>
                <read>
                    <type>dimensions</type>
                    <office>COMPANY_CODE</office>
                    <dimtype>SALARIS</dimtype>
                    <code>1234</code>
                </read>
            </twinfield:xmlRequest>
        </twinfield:ProcessXmlDocument>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: have a look at his as well: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71483325/simple-twinfield-api-request-with-postman
here I explain step by step how to get the data, this should work with below xml

Answer (score 0):

I'v had the same struggle as you are going through, after a while I contacted Twinfield about this and they offered me a slightly different soap xml, this is no where explained nor noted down but it worked so maybe it will work for you as well:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <h:Authentication xmlns:h="http://www.twinfield.com/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AccessToken xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Twinfield.WebServices.Shared">{{Accescode}}</AccessToken>
            <CompanyCode xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Twinfield.WebServices.Shared">{{Company}}</CompanyCode>
        </h:Authentication>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <Query i:type="b:GetDeletedTransactions" xmlns="http://www.twinfield.com/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Twinfield.WebServices" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Twinfield.WebServices.DeletedTransactionsService">
            <b:CompanyCode>{{Company}}</b:CompanyCode>
            <b:DateFrom>2022-06-01T00:00:00</b:DateFrom>
            <b:DateTo>2022-07-30T23:59:00</b:DateTo>
            <b:Daybook></b:Daybook>
        </Query>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

As you can see there a few parameters that you need to set the "Company" and the "Access code"

for the company list I've been using this xml request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:twin="http://www.twinfield.com/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <twin:Header>
            <twin:AccessToken>{{Accescode}}</twin:AccessToken>
        </twin:Header>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <twin:ProcessXmlString>
            <twin:xmlRequest><![CDATA[<list><type>offices</type></list>]]></twin:xmlRequest>
        </twin:ProcessXmlString>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

if these dont work it might be that your licence within the twinfield environment needs to be adjusted so you've access to this.

Comment: This looks promising, currently im on holiday but I will come back and test this as soon as I have time. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I tried your second request to get the list of offices, but I get the following error:
`Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: can you maybe post all the details you've used to send the request?

Comment: I have copied the exact code to get the company list but replaced the {{Accescode}} with my Access code